# Python compare a datetime with a str with the same format

Tags: python, datetime

I got this two values to compare

The first one came from a API with str format and the second one from function `datetime.datetime.now()`

```
2016-06-23 11:05:42.0
<class 'str'>

2016-06-23 18:00:03.063287
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I'm having problems to compare them

```
    if datetime.datetime.strftime(C[5],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') <= now:
        AA.append(C)
```

but it throws me the following error

> TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but
>   received a 'str'

Comment: You would use strptime but you don't actually need to use datetime as the strings can be safely compared lexicogrpahcally so just call `str(now)`.

Comment: No, I couldn't compare them directly. However strptime works. Thanks

Comment: how could you not? The time format is 24 hour, the date format is year-month-day so how would it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `strptime and parse the string to a datetime object:

```
In [27]: s = "2016-06-23 11:05:42.0"

In [28]: datetime.datetime.strptime(s,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
Out[28]: datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 23, 11, 5, 42)
```

but you don't actually need to use strptime as the strings could be safely compared lexicographically so you could just call str(now):

```
In [23]: "2016-06-23 11:05:42.0" < str(datetime.datetime.now())
Out[23]: True
In [24]: "2016-06-23 17:12:42.0" < str(datetime.datetime.now())
Out[24]: False
```